# Javascript Check Array with Object Keys using includes() but do not check the whole word

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code. A `body` object and a `sensitive` word array.

If the `body` key contains any word from `sensitive` words, it should returns true.

```
const body = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  otpp: ""
}
const sensitiveWords = ["password", "pin", "otp"]

const isSensitive = sensitiveWords.some(el => Object.keys(body).map(name => name.toLowerCase()).includes(el)) || false

console.log(isSensitive);
// returns: false
// expected result: true
```

But as you can see, the word `otp` is in the sensitive words, but its not matching `otpp`. I guess its because its looking for full string match.

I need the above function to return true since the key contains `otp` in `otpp`.

Thank you.

Comment: are you checking for the object keys only? or the whole object?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw only checking keys

Comment: Nice! I've put my answer below using a regexp :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for

```
const containsSensitive = sensitiveWords.some(el =>
  Object.keys(body).some(name =>
//                  ^^^^
    name.toLowerCase().includes(el)
//                     ^^^^^^^^ string search
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide an solution using double `some()` to do it

```js
const body = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  otpp: ""
}
let sensitiveWords = ["password", "pin", "otp"]

const isSensitive = (body,words) => Object.keys(body).map(n => n.toLowerCase()).some(d1 => words.some(d2 => d1.includes(d2)))

console.log(isSensitive(body,sensitiveWords)) // true

sensitiveWords = ["password", "pin", "otps"]
console.log(isSensitive(body,sensitiveWords)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regex with case insensitive flag (`i`). This could be more performant than using two nested loops.

```js
const body = {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  password: ''
}

const sensitiveWords = ['password', 'pin', 'otp']
const sensitiveWordsRegex = new RegExp(sensitiveWords.join('|'), 'i')

const keys = Object.keys(body)

const hasSensitiveWord = keys.some(key => sensitiveWordsRegex.test(key))

console.log(hasSensitiveWord)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) is the best one.
I just want to share what I worked on, I realized I made it so complicated.

Btw to explain why your code did not work is because:

- You were *searching the array for a word* (the *body object keys array* `Object.keys(body)`) -- this *will not work* because you are basically *comparing strings and not searching it for a substring*

What you need to do is ***search the string for a substring***

- You'll have to iterate through the *body keys* and search each for a substring --> `string.includes('string)`

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/medardm/fsq8Loe7/58/)

```js
/* 
** The answer of Bergi is the best one but just want to share what I worked on 
** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74150607/8414995) 
** if you want it the hard way
*/


// Check if strings from an array matches a key (substring or whole word) of an object
const body = {
  name: '', email: '', otpp: '',
}

// list of words to be searched in the body keys
const sensitiveWords = ['password', 'pin', 'otp']

// list down the keys first maybe to make the code clearer?
const bodyKeys = Object.keys(body)

// search through each word from sensitiveWords
const hasData = sensitiveWords.some(el => {
  // iterate through each word from bodyKeys and check if the sensitive word matches a substring of the body key. Filter only the true values
  const result = bodyKeys.map(bEl => {
    // return true if it matches anything
    if (bEl.includes(el)) {
      return true
    }
  }).filter(el => el == true)
  
  // the result will be in array form so let's just check if the length > 0
  return !!result.length
})

console.log(hasData) 


// Check if strings from an array matches a key (substring or whole word) of an object
```

Answer (score -3):

I would try to json stringify the whole body and split to words and search on that